# Ruby function call depending on provided parameters

Tags: ruby

```
def retrieve_transaction(from_when: '', to_when: '')
  from_when = Time.parse(from_when).to_i
  to_when = Time.parse(to_when).to_i

  starting_after = nil
  all_transaction = []
  loop do
    results = Stripe::BalanceTransaction.all(limit: 100, starting_after: starting_after, available_on: { gt: from_when, lt: to_when })
    break if results.data.length == 0
    all_transaction += results.data
    starting_after = results.data.last.id
  end
  all_transaction
end
```

This code is all about fetching transaction.
However if `from_when: '', to_when: ''` both are empty, I'd love to execute

`results = Stripe::BalanceTransaction.all(limit: 100, starting_after: starting_after)`

and if both of them are provided, I'd love to execute

`results = Stripe::BalanceTransaction.all(limit: 100, starting_after: starting_after, available_on: { gt: from_when, lt: to_when })`

I can write switch statement, or if statement, but I feel it's not efficient at all. Do you know any other better ways to handle this situation in more Ruby-way (I'm very new to Ruby ...)?

**Edit**

> What if one is empty and one is provided?

if `from_when: ''` is provided, 
`Stripe::BalanceTransaction.all(limit: 100, starting_after: starting_after, available_on: { gt: from_when})`
should be executed and vice versa.

Comment: What if one is empty and one is provided?

Comment: A way could be do wrap all parameter in a function which returns, depends on input, the best parameters. `Stripe::BalanceTransaction.all( build_params( from_when, to_when ) )`.

Comment: When you have an empty string, `Time.parse("")` will raise an error. What do you actually want in that case?

Comment: @sawa Because it's because to provide Unix time stamp..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will work in your case.
Build a hash of all the parameters you want to call the method with

```
params = {
  starting_after: starting_after
}

params[:available_on] = { 
  gt: from_when,
  lt: to_when
} unless (from_when.empty? || to_when.empty?)

...
results = Stripe::BalanceTransaction.all(params)
```